# how to add list of strings into an arraylist from console and the program should print the reverse of string on pressing ctrl+z

Tags: java

i am trying to add list of strings from my console and on pressing ctrl + z the list the console should stop taking input and print the strings in reverse order

i have code to print them back i want to know how the loop is written

```
public class Names {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         String one = sc.next();
         String two = sc.next();
         String three = sc.next();
         String four = sc.next();
         list.add(one);
        list.add(two);
        list.add(three);
        list.add(four);
        //System.out.println("size of list is :" +list.size());
            for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Which loop? The one in your code?

Comment: Curiosity - Why ctrl + z?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got a few things backwards.

First, CTRL + Z will cause a running process to be placed into the background and stop running (on Linux).  You probably don't want that; I would recommend instead that you stop taking input on some terminal value, like the empty string.

Second, you want to *indefinitely* take input into your list, and not just four elements.  The four `String` variables you have declared are pointless at best and serve to distract you from your true intention.  Your "gotcha" moment here is to avoid taking input forever; stop them when they enter in the empty string.  Here's a snippet/example:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    final String s = sc.nextLine();
    if(!"".equals(s)) {
        list.add(s);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Everything *else* looks fine (your loop  is fine for going in reverse).

Answer (score 0):

I would just add them backwards by adding the strings to the first position, then the printing code simplifies greatly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(String s = sc.next(); !s.isEmpty(); s = sc.next())
        list.add(0, s);
    for (String s : list)
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: From a performance standpoint, that's really expensive.  You have to do N shifts of data for every element you enter into the list, whereas in-order insertion is constant-time.  The printing code does greatly simplify, but I don't see any harm whatsoever in the other syntax; it feels like one is sacrificing performance for readability.

Comment: @Makoto yes, of course it sacrifices performance for readability, as all good code should, especially beginners code. "Optimizing early" is worse. Let's remember that the "slow insertion" part to which you refer will execute in a couple of microseconds - I doubt anyone would call that "slow".

Answer (score -1):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while(sc.hasNext()){
    list.add(sc.next());    
}

//System.out.println("size of list is :" +list.size());
for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));            
}
```

I just fixed your code to avoid Exception. If you entered two lines, the scanner will add two lines into the ArrayList and then the for loop will loop through the list and print them from backwards.

Let's say you entered 8 lines, the for loop will loop 7, 6, ...0. As per your code, the for loop will start the max-1 (8-1 = 7), then it will match for the condition (7>0); if the condition matches, it will print the value of ArrayList.

Comment: You've got an infinite loop.

Comment: I have tested in my machine!!

Comment: this code works once but once but if if try re running it it wont give output i have to close the program and restart it again

Comment: I believe ctrl+z will terminate the process and obviously it will kill the running java class.